# How to create a Generic Repository a 'deep include'?

Tags: c#, linq, repository, ef-code-first

I have created a Generic repository with some methods on top of EF Codefirst, which works great. The Get method looks like this (this has include for one level)

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "") 
{

        IQueryable<T> query = _dDbSet;

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        query = includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

        return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
    }
```

But I stumble on a problem when I need the generic repository to return a 'deeper' include

An example: A Hotel object have a relation to a list of rooms and each room have a relation to person.

I want my method to return a Hotel object with a list of rooms with the person of those rooms related.

How can I solve this by using a GenericRepository?

I do not want to use the solution:

```
    var hotel = _hotelRepository.Context.Hotels.Where(p => p.HotelId == HotelId).Include(p => p.RoomList.Select(b => b.Person)).First();
```

in my bussinesclass because I want to seperate out the data access to the genericRepository and be able to Mock out the method in my test project.

Is there a good solution for this, or do I have to use the context with a Select as mentioned above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I smell the [Inner-Platform Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). You are trying to make your generic repository do everything EF does. Why not use EF (or whatever ORM you use) directly?

Personally, I've ditched my own repositories a while ago. I encapsulate reusable queries by using the ORM directly in "report" classes. For simpler, one-off queries I use the ORM directly. When I write report classes or direct queries I know what to include/fetch eagerly etc and can use the tools the ORM offers.

Remember: your ORM already *is* the repository, no need to wrap it (IMO).

See http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Comment: Yea, this I see, and I try to keep my repository as small as posible. But more and more I see that my repository could need a new method to do a fetch with a 'deeper' include. I might be thinking this from the wrong angle. I don't have a problem using the ORM direcly, like the Select statement in my inital question. But its harder to mock out all the different context.hotel.where(h => h.id == etc) than GenericRepository.Get().

Comment: I understand that repositories are easy to mock and thus great for testing. But even without repositories you have options: 1) setup an in-memory DB (SQLite) for testing. Yes, it will not be a 100% isolated unit test anymore. 2) Move the part where you invoke the ORM into a virtual method, create a derived class, override those methods and inject the test values (basically apply the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)). 3) For complex queries, isolate them in separate class for which you inject fakes/mocks/stubs in your tests.